# Can not delete file on removable device

Tags: permission, git, macos

(This is on MacOS Monterey)

When performing a backup using `rsync --delete ....` to a USB stick, I noticed that there was a file which rsync could not delete, with error message *Operation not permitted*. I could verify this when I did manually a `rm -f ...` of this file. Checking the permissions of the file using `stat`, I see

```
16777231 936844 -rwxrwxrwx 1 ronaldfischer staff 0 692785057 "Mar 28 09:40:06 2023" "Sep 28 14:41:38 2020" "Sep 28 14:41:38 2020" "Nov 11 10:54:25 2022" 131072 1353216 0x2 /Volumes/SANKESU/gitwrk/vp5-e/.git/modules/repository/objects/pack/pack-f9012a97f8775c87b9d24fc0b4c276b883a6eb6a.pack
```

and checking the permissions on the directory which holds this file, I see

```
16777231 1125079 drwxrwxrwx 1 ronaldfischer staff 0 131072 "Nov 11 10:54:10 2022" "Apr 11 15:44:46 2023" "Apr 11 15:44:46 2023" "Nov 11 10:54:11 2022" 131072 256 0 /Volumes/SANKESU/gitwrk/vp5-e/.git/modules/repository/objects/pack
```

It does not look like a permission problem. What could be the reason?

BTW, from the time stamp given in the *stat* command, I can conclude that both directory and file had been created by a `rsync` running on Windows/Cygwin, but I don't see how this would explain the error message.

Other files in the backup of my repo are deleted without problems by *rsync*. Problems seem to occur only in entries which are located below `.git/objects`. I am aware that when doing the backup, there is no real need to backup the directory `.git` as well (except that when doing it, I can `cd` into the backup of my repository and perform `git` commands), but still I would like to know the reason for this problem.

Comment: Was the file in use, by any chance?

Comment: @Allan : No, unless rsync has used it by itself, which is not likely. I also did not have a Finder window open on this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file, `pack-f9012a97f8775c87b9d24fc0b4c276b883a6eb6a.pack`, has the user immutable flag set. The field before the path/filename from the output of `stat` contains the file_flag (lock) which is `0x2` (user immutable flag).

Comment: Any idea how to remove this flag? On MacOS I don't have `chattr`.

Comment: Ah, I found a way: I located the file using Finder, did a context-click on the file name, and selected "Get Info".  Then a dialogue with information on this file appeared, and there was a checkmark on "Locked". I removed the checkmark, and now the file is unlocked. If you know of a less complicated way, please add it to your answer, as this would make it even more useful.